# Android Preference. Setting child default value when parent is disable

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, preferences

I'm working on simple Android application. I'm using C# and Xamarin but i believe that programing language doesn't matter in that case since all changes are in `.xml` file.

Ok so my problem is related with preference that have dependency to other preference. First let me show my code then I will try to explain what i asking about.

```
  <PreferenceCategory
  android:title="@string/Pref_battery_settings"
  android:key="pref_key_battery_settings">
<SwitchPreference
    android:title="@string/Pref_battery_track_title"
    android:summary="@string/Pref_battery_track_summary"
    android:key="Pref_battery_track"
    android:defaultValue="true"/>
<CheckBoxPreference
android:dependency="Pref_battery_track"
android:disableDependentsState="true"
android:title="@string/Pref_battery_track_battery_status_title"
android:summary="@string/Pref_battery_track_battery_status_summary"
android:key="Pref_battery_track_status"
android:defaultValue="false"/>
```

As You can see i have 2 preference. First `Pref_battery_track` is `SwitchPreference` that will determine is my app will track battery ( levels ect. ) If that preference will be setted to `TRUE` user will be able to use second preference which will decide if we want to track battery status or nor ( status is e.g Charging, Discharging ect.). In logical thinking if we set first preference to true we can decide do we want to track more information or not but right now i have problem. When i set `Pref_battery_track` to `true` then `Pref_battery_track_status` also to `true` and switch back first preference to `false` second will be still as `true` and we will be able to do code like :

```
var prefs = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
var t =  prefs.GetBoolean("Pref_battery_track_status", false);
```

This code will return true when `Pref_battery_track_status` will be true even when `Pref_battery_track` will be fasle. So my question is : Is there any way to set child preference to default value when parent preference is `false` ?

Hope you know what i asking about.

And yes i know that i can simply check before i use child preference like`

```
var prefs = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
if(prefs.GetBoolean("Pref_battery_track", false))
{
var t = prefs.GetBoolean("Pref_battery_track_status", false);
 // Do things 
}`
```

But this solution is not nice since every time before i use child preference i will have to check parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subscribe the `PreferenceChange` event of your `SwitchPreference`, for example like this:

```
var switchp = PreferenceScreen.FindPreference("Pref_battery_track");
switchp.PreferenceChange += Switchp_PreferenceChange;
```

And then in `Switchp_PreferenceChange` set the `Checked` property of `CheckBoxPreference` for example:

```
private void Switchp_PreferenceChange(object sender, PreferenceChangeEventArgs e)
{
    var isenabled = (bool)e.NewValue;
    if (!isenabled)
    {
        var checkp = PreferenceScreen.FindPreference("Pref_battery_track_status") as CheckBoxPreference;
        checkp.Checked = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello. I tried your solution and it work fine for me. If there is not possible to set it in `.xml` file this solution work perfect. Thanks.